# Traer un JSON en un array en Angular

Tags: angular, json, typescript, frontend

Mi problema es que al querer traer un json de una api que yo hice y probe en PostMan que funcionaba simplemente en forma de prueba
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al querer llevarla a mi Front en Angular no puedo y nose en que estoy errando, les dejo el Service, el model y el .TS
[image: Service]

y me asegure que el URL sea exactamente el mismo que probe en Postman

[image: Model]

[image: El typeScrip de mi modulo]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: que te muestra console.log(data[0])?

Answer (score 0):

En el servicio donde dice: `public lista():Observable<Experiencia[]>{...}`
cámbialo por `lista(){...}` ahora en tu `cargarExp()` de tu componente cuando imprimes console.log(data) que te trae, ese `this.experiencia` ¿como está declarado?
Da mayor detalle de tu inconveniente.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

La informaación te está llegando como un observable, por lo que al definirlo así debes de hacer un pipe y un map si la cantidad de información es mucha o simplemente un pipe y después un tap si es una sola lista, todos estos son elementos de rxjs

En teoría debería verse así:

```
return this.httpClient.get<Experiencia[]>(this.expURL + '/listaexp').pipe(
tap((respuesta) => { return respuesta }));
```

así al hacer tu subscribe te deberá dar los datos.